# Python: convert string from UTF-8 to Latin-1

Tags: python, encoding

I feel stacked here trying to change encodings with Python 2.5

I have XML response, which I encode to UTF-8: `response.encode('utf-8')`. That is fine, but the program which uses this info doesn't like this encoding and I have to convert it to other code page. Real example is that I use ghostscript python module to embed pdfmark data to a PDF file - end result is with wrong characters in Acrobat.

I've done numerous combinations with `.encode()` and `.decode()` between 'utf-8' and 'latin-1' and it drives me crazy as I can't output correct result.

If I output the string to a file with `.encode('utf-8')` and then convert this file from UTF-8 to CP1252 (aka latin-1) with i.e. **iconv.exe** and embed the data everything is fine.

Basically can someone help me convert i.e. character **á** which is UTF-8 encoded as hex: `C3 A1` to latin-1 as hex: `E1`?

Comment: CP1252 is **NOT** Latin1!

Comment: ok, there is minor difference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Comment: The most accurate was to convert Unicode to Latin1 in a variable `s` is this way: `s = "ALL INFORMATION IRRECOVERABLY LOST"`. I believe you will find this algorithm to be faster than any other you might attempt — and the most honest.

Comment: I was trying to encode letter "Ñ" (uppercase), with latin1, and it failed, the rest of letter were correct. But, cp1252 did it! :D

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of `.encode('utf-8')`, use `.encode('latin-1')`.

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe it's so simple and what was I doing? I tryed it before but as `.encode('latin-1', 'ignore')` all the time like I use it when I encode 'ascii'

Comment: Above comment doesn't make sense. Both methods (with or w/o 'ignore') are working fine now :o Thanks to both. I need some sleep :|

Comment: @funtuku: What tchrist is trying to convey to you is that ignorance is NOT bliss, and "ignoring a non-encoded character" is NOT a better choice, and there are several tens of thousands (counting only the BMP) of Unicode characters that can't be encoded in latin1's set 192 characters and 64 controls, and there is no .encode arg that is similar to "ignore", and consequently ...

Comment: This answer is incorrect for Python 3. s.encode('latin-1') will throw an exception if it contains a non-latin-1 character.  For example, 'commanderâ€™s'.encode('latin-1') will throw an exception, but 'commanderâ€™s'.encode('utf-8') will not.

Comment: @ProfMo That's not a bug, it's a feature. You can easily discard the exception if you want, but you shouldn't because in doing so you are discarding data.

Answer (score 6):

```
data="UTF-8 data"
udata=data.decode("utf-8")
data=udata.encode("latin-1","ignore")
```

Should do it.

Comment: Might as well just discard everything but A-M.

Comment: It would discard the special characters only not found in latin-1 encoding but found in utf-8 encoding.

Comment: I’m quite aware of what it would do. I stand by my statement.

Comment: @tchrist: what's up with the attitude?  If the OP knows that his data falls in the latin-1 range, but it getting it in utf-8, and wants it in latin-1, this is fine.

Comment: @Ned: It’s fine to convert to Latin-1 **if and only if** you do not discard errors.

Comment: @tchrist: that's a more helpful comment.  Even better would be a discussion of the issues with sample code to help the OP find his way.

Comment: @tchrist. I get what you are saying. I think using "strict" or "replace" instead of "ignore" would be a better choice instead of ignoring the errors sometimes. The replace parameter replaces the unknown characters with a question mark.

Comment: @Ned, as far as I can tell, something else is going wrong with the OP’s situation, since Acrobat should certainly have no problem with Unicode. He must be writing UTF-8 to a file that is already in ISO-8859-1, which means he chose the wrong encoding. But he needs to detect errors, because they mean that he can’t do what he wants and instead needs to upgrade the original to the larger character repertoire.

Comment: @funktku: Every day on the job I have to deal with mutilated text files full of `?` characters caused by ignorant programmers screwing up. It’s *really* irritating!

Comment: @tchrist: I get why sometimes it is necessary. Please next time instead of bashing another idea, try to explain why in that particular case your solution is a better choice.

Comment: [UTR#36 2.6.1 Missing Glyphs:](http://unicode.org/reports/tr36/) “It is very important not to show a missing glyph or character with a simple "?", because every such character is visually confusable with a real question mark.”

Comment: If I run your code I get an error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Answer (score 4):

Can you provide more details about what you are trying to do? In general, if you have a unicode string, you can use encode to convert it into string with appropriate encoding. Eg:

```
>>> a = u"\u00E1"
>>> type(a)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> a.encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\xa1'
>>> a.encode('latin-1')
'\xe1'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the previous answers do not solve your problem, check the source of the data that won't print/convert properly.

In my case, I was using `json.load` on data incorrectly read from file by not using the `encoding="utf-8"`. Trying to de-/encode the resulting string to `latin-1` just does not help...