# Can't not get content from URL with python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying get content from an Chinese web page with python and BeautifulSoup.However when i print the result,i get nothing in the console.So,can anybody tell me why?(ps:i also change with some other web pages,sometimes the code works,but sometimes it doesn't)
  Here is my code:

```
# _*_ coding:utf-8 _*_
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import urllib
import urllib2

url='http://finance.sina.com.cn/chanjing/cyxw/2015-12-17/doc-ifxmttcn4893506.shtml'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
try:
  request=urllib2.Request(url)
  response=urllib2.urlopen(request)
  html=response.read()
  content=BeautifulSoup(response)
  print content
except  urllib2.URLError,e:
   if hasattr(e,"code"):
      print e.code
   if hasattr(e,"reason"):
      print e.reason
```

Here is my result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAxxu.png)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
page = requests.get('http://finance.sina.com.cn/chanjing/cyxw/2015-12-17/doc-ifxmttcn4893506.shtml')
print page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)
soup.prettify()
print soup
```

Comment: Sorry,i start python recently,and i can't understand your code.What does requests.get() mean?Is that a method in python?

Comment: it will go to given url and return that page's whole content.

Comment: for that you have to import requests module in your file.

Comment: but my python interpreter tells me that name 'requests' is not defined.I'm using python 2.7.

Comment: did you import requests?

Comment: i didn't download it before.Now i am downloading

Comment: i came up with another question.my result get garbled.Is there any way to fix it

Comment: i don't understand what you want to say!

Comment: Sorry...I mean the web page is encode with utf-8,so how should i decode with soup.content and print it correctly .Because the chinese character is garbled characters in my output

Comment: what you print **soup** or **page.text**

Comment: i have known how to deal with it.By the way,you are so nice!Thank you!

Comment: Most Welcome, you also nice guy.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
content=BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Comment: I have tried this,but i only got garbled.(somethins like this:'C:\Python27\python.exe C:/pythoncode/spiderforsina.py
<html><body><p>‹      ì½i{GÖ?üzøMOK±¶–,ïmc²Á6`CÀŽGWKjËmKj¡–¼€u]ÎBBHÉ„I2Y</p></body></html>

Process finished with exit code 0
'

Comment: This is an encoding problem. The page is encoded in UTF-8 but it seems that your console is displaying it in another encoding. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299802/python-convert-string-from-utf-8-to-latin-1) can help you.